# How to add a (SEH) exception handler dynamically for a 64-bit function?

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, portable-executable, seh

Say, if I have a function that is injected into another 64-bit process (for instance, using [CreateRemoteThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx)) and I want to implement *Structured Exception Handling* in that function (otherwise done via `__try`, `__except`, `__finally` blocks), can I add the SEH handler/filter dynamically?

PS. The reason I'm asking is because [SEH is no longer implemented via a stack frame](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=469) in 64-bit processes (as it used to be in x86.) All SEH entries are now in the PE header of the target process image file.

Comment: [RtlAddFunctionTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680588(v=vs.85).aspx). It is intended for jitters.

Comment: @RaymondChen: A code example would really help. I was able to set a filter with `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` but how do you set the handler with `RtlAddFunctionTable`?

Comment: I have never done this either, but I was hoping this would be a nudge in the right direction. From there, you can see the documentation for [x64 RUNTIME_FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft9x1kdx.aspx) which says that you give an RVA to [UNWIND_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddssxxy8.aspx), and that lets you specify the RVA of the handler.