# How is table-based exception handling better than 32-bit Windows SEH?

Tags: windows, exception, abi, seh

In 32-bit Windows (at least with Microsoft compilers), exception handling [is implemented](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/Win32SEH.chm/Win32SEH.htm) using a stack of exception frames allocated dynamically on the call stack; the top of the exception stack is pointed to by a TIB entry. The runtime cost is a couple of `PUSH`/`POP` instructions per function that needs to handle exceptions, spilling the variables accessed by the exception handler onto the stack, and when handling an exception, a simple linked list walk.

In both [64-bit Windows](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=469) and the [Itanium / System V x86-64 ABI](http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html), unwinding instead uses a big sorted list describing all the functions in memory. The runtime cost is some tables per *every* function (not just ones involved in exception handling), [complications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48675663) for dynamically generated code, and when handling an exception, walking the function list once per every active function *regardless* of whether it has anything to do with exceptions or not.

How is the latter better than the former? I understand why the Itanium model is cheaper in the common case than the traditional UNIX one based on `setjmp`/`longjmp`, but a couple of `PUSH`es and`POP`s plus some register spillage in 32-bit Windows doesn't seem that bad, for the (seemingly) much quicker and simpler handling that it provides. (IIRC, Windows API calls routinely consume Ks of stack space anyway, so it’s not like we gain anything by forcing this data out into tables.)

Comment: There's a slight performance advantage of table driven exception handling. Throwing an exception is costly anyway, but that dosn't happen often and handling a resource collapse isn't the relevant case. The performance-relevant case is when no exception is thrown and that costs nothing with table-driven EH.

Comment: @BonitaMontero That’s the standard answer, yes, but it seems dubious to me. I buy it for Linux, where before Itanium-style tables the only option (probably due to the Borland patent) was setjmp/longjmp (aka SJLJ), which is both code-heavy in the happy case and basically takes a hammer to register allocation. Traditional Win32 SEH is much better in that respect AFAICT. The cost is also not exactly zero, as the tables can be pretty heavy—I haven’t done a comparison on Windows, but on Linux the rule of thumb seems to be that adding asynchronous unwinding to plain C code bloats it up by 30%.

Comment: Also, of course “throwing an exception ... doesn’t happen often” if you make it expensive, because programmers will adapt; yet cultures where it isn’t [have developed styles](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html) which successfully use unwinding for somewhat infrequent yet perfectly ordinary and non-erroneous events. (That sounds horrible if you’re used to conventional exceptions, but with a slight extension of the idea it becomes quite lovely.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to optimizing the happy case, perhaps there was also a concern that buffer overflow vulnerabilities could expose the information in the exception.  If this information gets corrupted, it could seriously confuse the user, or maybe even cause further errors (remember std::terminate() is called if another exception gets thrown).

Source: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm%5earticle=469.htm

Comment: Overwriting exception frames as way to turn a buffer overflow into code execution is well known today, but table-driven SEH seems to have been introduced with Windows XP for the Itanium (2001), which basically didn’t *need* code execution vectors—what with such gems as ActiveX in the browser and wide-open DCOM. I don’t get the impression that anybody at Microsoft was thinking in these terms at the time (though in 2006, when the linked article was written, the situation was certainly different). It’s possible that somebody did, but so far I haven’t encountered any contemporary evidence.